# Draw `MTLTexture` to `CAMetalLayer`

Tags: ios, objective-c, metal, skia

I am drawing stuff onto an off-screen `MTLTexture`. (using Skia Canvas)

At a later point, I want to render this `MTLTexture` into a `CAMetalLayer` to display it on the screen.

Since I was using Skia for the off-screen drawing operations, my code is quite simple and **I don't have the typical Metal setup** (no `MTLLibrary`, `MTLRenderPipelineDescriptor`, `MTLRenderPassDescriptor`, `MTLRenderEncoder`, etc).

I now simply want to draw that `MTLTexture` into a `CAMetalLayer`, but haven't figured out how to do so simply.

This is where I draw my stuff to the `MTLTexture _texture` (Skia code):

```
- (void) renderNewFrameToCanvas(Frame frame) {
  if (_skContext == nullptr) {
    GrContextOptions grContextOptions;
    _skContext = GrDirectContext::MakeMetal((__bridge void*)_device,
                                            // TODO: Use separate command queue for this context?
                                            (__bridge void*)_commandQueue,
                                            grContextOptions);
  }

  @autoreleasepool {
    // Lock Mutex to block the runLoop from overwriting the _texture
    std::lock_guard lockGuard(_textureMutex);

    auto texture = _texture;

    // Get & Lock the writeable Texture from the Metal Drawable
    GrMtlTextureInfo fbInfo;
    fbInfo.fTexture.retain((__bridge void*)texture);
    GrBackendRenderTarget backendRT(texture.width,
                                    texture.height,
                                    1,
                                    fbInfo);

    // Create a Skia Surface from the writable Texture
    auto skSurface = SkSurface::MakeFromBackendRenderTarget(_skContext.get(),
                                                            backendRT,
                                                            kTopLeft_GrSurfaceOrigin,
                                                            kBGRA_8888_SkColorType,
                                                            nullptr,
                                                            nullptr);

    auto canvas = skSurface->getCanvas();
    auto surface = canvas->getSurface();

    // Clear anything that's currently on the Texture
    canvas->clear(SkColors::kBlack);

    // Converts the Frame to an SkImage - RGB.
    auto image = SkImageHelpers::convertFrameToSkImage(_skContext.get(), frame);
    canvas->drawImage(image, 0, 0);

    // Flush all appended operations on the canvas and commit it to the SkSurface
    canvas->flush();

    // TODO: Do I need to commit?
    /*
    id<MTLCommandBuffer> commandBuffer([_commandQueue commandBuffer]);
    [commandBuffer commit];
     */
  }
}
```

Now, since I have the `MTLTexture _texture` in memory, I want to draw it to the `CAMetalLayer _layer`. This is what I have so far:

```
- (void) setup {
  // I set up a runLoop that calls render() 60 times a second.
  // [removed to simplify]

  _renderPassDescriptor = [[MTLRenderPassDescriptor alloc] init];
  
  // Load the compiled Metal shader (PassThrough.metal)
  auto baseBundle = [NSBundle mainBundle];
  auto resourceBundleUrl = [baseBundle URLForResource:@"VisionCamera" withExtension:@"bundle"];
  auto resourceBundle = [[NSBundle alloc] initWithURL:resourceBundleUrl];
  auto shaderLibraryUrl = [resourceBundle URLForResource:@"PassThrough" withExtension:@"metallib"];
  
  NSError* libLoadError;
  id<MTLLibrary> defaultLibrary = [_device newLibraryWithURL:shaderLibraryUrl error:&libLoadError];
  id<MTLFunction> vertexFunction = [defaultLibrary newFunctionWithName:@"vertexPassThrough"];
  id<MTLFunction> fragmentFunction = [defaultLibrary newFunctionWithName:@"fragmentPassThrough"];
  
  if (vertexFunction == nil || fragmentFunction == nil) {
    throw std::runtime_error("VisionCamera: Failed to load PassThrough.metal shader!");
  }
  
  // Create a Pipeline Descriptor that connects the CPU draw operations to the GPU Metal context
  auto pipelineDescriptor = [[MTLRenderPipelineDescriptor alloc] init];
  pipelineDescriptor.label = @"VisionCamera: Frame Texture -> Layer Pipeline";
  pipelineDescriptor.vertexFunction = vertexFunction;
  pipelineDescriptor.fragmentFunction = fragmentFunction;
  pipelineDescriptor.colorAttachments[0].pixelFormat = MTLPixelFormatBGRA8Unorm;
  
  NSError* error;
  _pipelineState = [_device newRenderPipelineStateWithDescriptor:pipelineDescriptor error:&error];
  if (error != nil) {
    throw std::runtime_error("VisionCamera: Failed to create render pipeline state!");
  }
}
    
// gets called 60 times a second to draw to the screen
- (void) render() {
  @autoreleasepool {
    // Blocks until the next Frame is ready (16ms at 60 FPS)
    auto drawable = [_layer nextDrawable];
    
    std::unique_lock lock(_textureMutex);
    auto texture = _texture;
    
    MTLRenderPassDescriptor* renderPassDescriptor = [[MTLRenderPassDescriptor alloc] init];
    renderPassDescriptor.colorAttachments[0].texture = drawable.texture;
    renderPassDescriptor.colorAttachments[0].loadAction = MTLLoadActionClear;
    renderPassDescriptor.colorAttachments[0].clearColor = MTLClearColor();
    
    id<MTLCommandBuffer> commandBuffer([_commandQueue commandBuffer]);
    
    auto renderEncoder = [commandBuffer renderCommandEncoderWithDescriptor:renderPassDescriptor];
    [renderEncoder setLabel:@"VisionCamera: PreviewView Texture -> Layer"];
    [renderEncoder setRenderPipelineState:_pipelineState];
    [renderEncoder setFragmentTexture:texture atIndex:0];
    [renderEncoder endEncoding];
    
    [commandBuffer presentDrawable:drawable];
    [commandBuffer commit];
    
    lock.unlock();
  }
}
```

And along with that, I have created the `PassThrough.metal` shader which is just for passing through a texture:

```
#include <metal_stdlib>
using namespace metal;

// Vertex input/output structure for passing results from vertex shader to fragment shader
struct VertexIO
{
    float4 position [[position]];
    float2 textureCoord [[user(texturecoord)]];
};

// Vertex shader for a textured quad
vertex VertexIO vertexPassThrough(const device packed_float4 *pPosition  [[ buffer(0) ]], const device packed_float2 *pTexCoords [[ buffer(1) ]], uint vid [[ vertex_id ]]) {
    VertexIO outVertex;

    outVertex.position = pPosition[vid];
    outVertex.textureCoord = pTexCoords[vid];

    return outVertex;
}

// Fragment shader for a textured quad
fragment half4 fragmentPassThrough(VertexIO inputFragment [[ stage_in ]], texture2d<half> inputTexture  [[ texture(0) ]], sampler samplr [[ sampler(0) ]]) {
    return inputTexture.sample(samplr, inputFragment.textureCoord);
}
```

Running this crashes the app with the following exception:

```
validateRenderPassDescriptor:782: failed assertion `RenderPass Descriptor Validation
Texture at colorAttachment[0] has usage (0x01) which doesn't specify MTLTextureUsageRenderTarget (0x04)
```

This now raises three questions for me:

1. Do I have to do all of that Metal setting up, packing along the `PassThrough.metal` shader, render pass stuff, etc just to draw the `MTLTexture` to the `CAMetalLayer`? Is there no simpler way?
2. Why is the code above failing?
3. When is the drawing from Skia actually committed to the MTLTexture? Do I need to commit the command buffer (as seen in my TODO)?